# In app review doesn't work after app production

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, review, rate

I am just trying to pop a google review dialog inside the app but it doesn't work note the app has already been released

i add it a gradle links

and add the code

gradle

```
implementation("com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0")
implementation("com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.0")
```

Code

```
fun requestStoreReview(activity: Activity, runnable: Runnable) {
    val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(activity)
    val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
    request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // We got the ReviewInfo object
            val reviewInfo = task.result
            if (reviewInfo != null) {
                startReview(activity, reviewInfo, manager, runnable);
            }
        } else {
            // There was some problem, log or handle the error code.
            // @ReviewErrorCode val reviewErrorCode = (task.getException() as TaskException).errorCode
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(Exception(task.exception));
        }
    }

}

private fun startReview(
    activity: Activity,
    reviewInfo: ReviewInfo,
    manager: ReviewManager,
    runnable: Runnable
) {
    val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo)
    flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
        // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
        // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
        // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
        runnable.run()
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Review App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
      rateClicked?.setOnClickListener{
            activity?.let { it1 -> requestStoreReview(it1, Runnable {  }) }
        }
```

Comment: Did you publish the release build on Google Play and it doesn't work?

Comment: yes i did it and it doesn't  work